# IndexOutOfBoundException while writing to a file

Tags: java, file, io, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm using this code to write to a file , and it throws `IndexOutOfBoundException`.

```
InputStream is = res.openStream();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
byte[] array = new byte[1024];
for(int i = is.read(array); i != 1; i=is.read(array)) {
        fos.write(array, 0, i);
}
```

how can I check how many bytes left to write?

Comment: your for loop breaks only if i is different than `1`. When there is nothing to read, the `is.read` method however returns -1.

Comment: wow I missed that somehow

Comment: It is usually the small stuff which is easy to miss :) Happens to everybody all the time.

Comment: I thought it somehow connected to the last bytes left to write

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When there is nothing to read, the `read` method returns `-1` and not `1`.
Therefore the check in your loop must be:

```
for(int i = is.read(array); i != -1; i=is.read(array))
```